# Attempting to join: error "Conversion failed when converting from a character string to uniqueidentifier."

Tags: string, join, type-conversion, uniqueidentifier

I am getting the following error when attempting to join on two ID fields:

select top 10 *

from SOURCECODE as s

inner join APPEAL as a on s.APPEALID = a.APPEALID;

error: **Conversion failed when converting from a character string to uniqueidentifier.**

Any ideas on how to fix?

Do I need to convert the fields?

The s.appealid is nvarchar 36

The a.appealid is uniqueidentifier

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT TOP 10 *
FROM SOURCECODE AS s
INNER JOIN APPEAL AS a ON CONVERT(uniqueidentifier, s.APPEALID) = a.APPEALID;
```

Comment: Explanation....?